# How to encrypt sqlserver password using python or jython

Tags: python, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2, jython

This is my sql server conn stmt

```
conn = sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://TESTDEV\NI1:1433;databaseName=DEV_FDMEE;user=test_dev;password=2020TSTuser;");
```

I need to encrypt the passowrd of `2020TSTuser` using python or jython script .I tried various methods but it did not work.so please provide me with a sample script ,looking forward to hear from experts

Comment: Encrypt it for what purpose? So other users can't read the password from the source file?

Comment: Which various methods did you use and how did it fail?

Comment: User Should not read the password from the jython script.It should be encrypted.Please provide me with the script to encrypt the password

Comment: @SHARIHARHARI, the script will need to decrypt the password before using it. If the script can decrypt it the user can decrypt it. You're probably better served by making sure your config file is only accessible to trusted users, e.g. through filesystem permissions.

Comment: I have created a DB link on the sql server called TEST 
and created a system dsn called Link for the databaseName=DEV_FDMEE
user=test_dev
password=2020TSTuser

and tested the linked server connection it was successful

i dont know the right way to pass the DB link on the python script.The reason for testing this db link is to hide the db password